# Rails doesn't display html tags in title of a page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I would like to display html tags in title of a page via Rails. I'm using Rails 2.3 I've tried these ways

```
<title><%= raw @agent_event_monitor.name %></title>
<title><%= @agent_event_monitor.name.html_safe %></title>
<title><pre><code><%= @agent_event_monitor.name.html_safe %></code></pre></title>
<title><%= h(@agent_event_monitor.name) %></title>
```

but none doesn't give any result on @agent_event_monitor.name is something like this

```
<b><p>Hello</p></b>
```

Comment: what do you see in the HTML source for all 4 scenarios?

Comment: No, emallein meant which html code did you see?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to replicate the scenario. See below:

[image]

In application.haml:

```
%title= "<b><p>Hello</p></b>".html_safe
```